# how to get the instagram_business_account_id using a test user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Created a test user on the Facebook developer panel. Created a page, and linked my Instagram user to this test user but I can't get the `instagram_business_account_id` of the Instagram user.

Getting the `page id` :

```
GET: https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/<test_user_id>/accounts?access_token=<test_user_access_token>
```

Getting the `instagram_business_account_id`

```
GET: https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/<test_user_page_id>?access_token=<test_user_access_token>&fields=instagram_business_account
```

Reponse:

```
javascript
Response: {
    "id": "<fb_page_id>" //  Facebook Page ID
}
```

`instagram_business_account_id` did not come in the response.

Response example from graph api documentation

```
javascript
{
  "instagram_business_account": {
    "id": "17841405822304914"  // Connected IG User ID
  },
  "id": "134895793791914"  // Facebook Page ID
}
```

How do I get the `instagram_business_account_id` of the Instagram user linked to this test user?

Details:

- I added all the permissions available to the test user but it didn't work either.
- the Instagram account linked to this test user is a business account.

Comment: Does the access token you are using meet the following requirements: 
A Facebook User access token with the following permissions:
`instagram_basic`
`pages_show_list`
If the token is from a User whose Page role was granted via the Business Manager, one of the following permissions is also required:
`ads_management`
`pages_read_engagement`
`business_management`

Comment: Thanks for reply. the access token already has these permissions. In fact, for testing purposes, I added all the permissions to validate if it was indeed a permission issue, but I still don't get the access token.

Comment: detail: I updated these permissions directly from the test user's "edit" button on the Facebook developer page.

Comment: Hmm, can you submit a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/create and provide the link to the report in a comment here. We'll be able to inspect your app and token that way.

Comment: ok, thanks @AndrewL.